# CSS rule set within another CSS rule set

Tags: html, css

I saw the following code style which is something that is completely new to me:

```
#nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  ul {
    li {
      float: left;
      a {
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0 10px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the technical name for this and where can I read up on it?

Comment: That is code from a CSS-preprocessor, like SASS or LESS.

Comment: SASS: http://sass-lang.com/ and LESS: http://lesscss.org/

Comment: If you're dealing a lot with CSS, I would really recommend to dig on either SASS or LESS, as they have made web development much much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is syntax for a CSS pre-processor. They allow you to use things like variables and selector nesting to create your CSS selectors.

For example a Less file might look like this:

@color: #CCC;

```
ul {
    background-color: @color;
    li {
        color: red;
        &:hover {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
    .home & {
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

Would compile to:

```css
ul {
    background-color: #CCC;
}
ul li {
    color: red;
    }
ul li:hover {
    color: blue;
    }
.home ul {
    background-color: black;
}
```

The two most popular options:

- [Less](http://lesscss.org/)
- [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: I saw it here http://codepen.io/JoelSutherland/pen/DzbfE though, no preprocessor is used. How is this possible?

Comment: They are using a preprocessor, noticed the middle column is labeled **CSS** and then in parenthesis it says **(LESS)**.

Comment: Ah saw it now. Thanks!